# The composite of three mappings is not surjective if one of them is not surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I´m stuck in the process of proving the next proposition:

> Given the sets $A, B, C$ and $D$; and the functions $f:A\to B$, $g:B\to C$, $h:C\to D$such that $f$ and $h$ are bijective. Show that if $g$ is injective but not surjective, then $h \circ g\circ f$ is an inyective function but not surjective.

---

### My solution.

There are some ideas that i think are needed to be clear in the beginning, beside the definitions of injective and surjective funtions, we need the negation of the last one, which in my understandig would be:

> If $g$ is not surjective $\implies \exists$  $c\in C$ such that $c\neq g(b) $ $\forall  b\in B$.

From there, I started analysing the injectivity:

- The composite of two injective maps is injective:

Given $a_1 ,a_2 \in A$. Suppose $g(f(a_1))=g(f(a_2))$, since $g$ is injective $\implies f(a_1)=f(a_2)$. And since $f$ is also injective $\implies a_1=a_2$. So $g\circ f$ is injective.

Similarly, since $h$ is injective $\implies h \circ g\circ f$ is injective also.

Now, i proceded with the surjectivity:

- The composite of two surjective maps is surjective:

In this case, since $g$ is not surjcetive $\implies \exists$  $c\in C$ such that $c\neq g(b) $ $\forall  b\in B$.

Since $f$ is surjective, let $b:=f(a)$ such that $c\neq g(f(a)) $ $\forall  a\in A$.

Which translates to $g\circ f$ is not surjective.

### Where I got stuck

The following step would de proving that $h \circ g\circ f$ is not surjective, but i cannot see how to achieve this.

Since $h$ is bijective, there exist a $c$ which is not mapped by $g$ but it´s mapped by $h$, but it won´t be mapped by the composition either.

And i can´t se how to express this. Somehow applying $h$ to $g\circ f$ which has already be proven is not surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c \in C$ be outside of the image of $g$. Let $d = h(c)$. To show that $d$ is not in the image of $h \circ g \circ f$, you need to use the injectivity of $h$: Suppose $d = h(g(f(a)))$ for some $a \in A$. Then by injectivity of $h$, $g(f(a)) = c$, a contradiction.